# Cant prevent a link click with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have got this html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"  data-ref="su1c2cess" class="Wifewriting" id="target_site_to_visit">
    <span data-app-id="63" class="btn" id="visit_site" style="right:22px; top:65px; padding:5px;z-index: -99999;">VISIT SITE</span>
</a>
```

**UPDATE**
And this is my jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('body').on('click','#target_site_to_visit',function(event){
           var appName=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('class');
           var referrer=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('data-ref');
          $.post('db/update_site_viewed.php',{ name:appName, ref:referrer }, function(data){



      throw new Error("AppName: "+appName);

      },'html').error(function(data){

      throw new Error("Error: "+data.responseText);
      });
    // document.location.href=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('href');
return false;
  });

});
```

The `event.preventDefault();` does nothing in stopping the link from being triggered.. why?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: no, cause it quickly switches to another page. ...there is no way to stop it

Comment: Can you change the link `href` then? There is probably an error in your code that causes the JS to not be executed.

Comment: Try commenting out the rest of the code after the preventDefault(); You clearly have an error somewhere in your code that is making that event barf.

Comment: Which page opens when you click the link? There's apparently no `href` in it. Are you sure there's no other click handler for that element (and that you ctrl+F5'd your browser to load the new js file with the comment location line)?

Comment: okay, i modified my answer..see update

Comment: You removed the `event.preventDefault()` from the click handler and added a `return false` in the `.ready` function? That's why indenting is important. `=]`

Comment: very true.. i will put it back.. i doubt it will work

Comment: It should work with a valid markup and no JS errors.. http://jsfiddle.net/rVJ8U/

Comment: Make sure you don't have duplicate IDs and that the jQuery lib is properly included in your page, just a shot in the dark. But the problem is not in the code above.

Comment: true. it does work.. another question, you can see that i use post method...to see obtained data do I use this in my success function: data.responseText. please post your full answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there are no errors in your console and valid markup, `return false` will prevent the event's default action and prevent it from bubbling up the DOM as you know.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','#target_site_to_visit',function(event){
        var appName=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('class');
        var referrer=$('#target_site_to_visit').attr('data-ref');
        $.post('db/update_site_viewed.php',{ name:appName, ref:referrer }, function(data){
            throw new Error("AppName: "+appName);
        }, 'html').error(function(data){
            throw new Error("Error: "+data.responseText);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And to use the obtained data, use the first parameter in the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)'s callback function which returns the fetched data:

```
$.post('db/update_site_viewed.php',{ name:appName, ref:referrer }, function(data){
        console.log(data); //<-- fetched html will be displayed in the console
}, html);
```

Inside the callback function you can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and similar methods to add the data to the DOM, as well as being able to manipulate it as a string, get sub-elements of it by wrapping the `data` inside the a jQuery object `$(data)`,  and well, do basically everything you want with it.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) docs, I would make sure your function returns false.

> Returning false from an event handler will automatically call
>   event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault().

Comment: `#target_site_to_visit` is an anchor tag.

Comment: no. even with return false, it doesnt work.. return false is a combination of stopPropogation and prevent default. I am actually pressing the link